# Undefined variable into an Observable

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, observable

Maybe is a noob question, but i can't find information about this. The problem is in a function that returns an Observable. When this is called, the parameter works, but into the Observable his value is `undefined`.

This is my function:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export function ToBase64(inputFile) {
    console.log('Input:', inputFile); //Here the variable has the correct value
    let observable = new Observable(observator => {
        try {
            console.log('Input en observable:', inputFile); //here is undefined :(
            var image = {};

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (e) => {
                image.base64 = btoa(e.target.result);

                var stringBase64 = `data:${image.filetype};base64,${image.base64}`;

                observator.next(stringBase64);
                observator.complete()
            };

            console.log(inputFile);
            var inputFile = inputFile.files[0];
            image.filetype = inputFile.type;
            image.size = inputFile.size;
            image.filename = inputFile.name;
            reader.readAsBinaryString(inputFile);
        } catch (e) {
            observator.error(e);
        }
    });

    return observable;
}
```

My function is called from an Angular2 App, like this:

```
//imports...

export class MedicosListComponent {
    @ViewChild('imagenMedico') imagenMedico:any;
    private image:string;

    constructor() {

    }

    showAllWeas() {
        ToBase64(this.imagenMedico.nativeElement).subscribe(
            data => {
                alert(data)
            },
            error => alert(error)
        )
    }
}
```

The `medicoList` variable is an input type file.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the problem in specific is the scope, only adding a extra variable in the function it works, like this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export function ToBase64(inputFile) {
    var i = inputFile; // <------- extra variable
    return new Observable(obs => {
        try {
            var image = {};
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (e) => {
                image.base64 = btoa(e.target.result);

                var stringBase64 = `data:${image.filetype};base64,${image.base64}`;

                obs.next(stringBase64);
                obs.complete()
            };

            var inputFile = i.files[0]; //here i has the correct value
            image.filetype = inputFile.type;
            image.size = inputFile.size;
            image.filename = inputFile.name;
            reader.readAsBinaryString(inputFile);
        } catch (e) {
            obs.error(e);
        }
    });
}
```

That is all.